# How to fix Brew's symlink errors when Brew thinks the link already exists?

Tags: homebrew, symlink

Please help understand what is going on--or whether any action is required. I've gone through a lot of posts on dealing with brew, node, symlink, uninstalled and reinstalled node, npm, yarn, tried `brew cleanup`. When `brew doctor` produced these warnings--

```
 Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/JSONStream
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/errno
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/is-ci
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/opener
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/qrcode-terminal
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/rc
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/semver
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/sshpk-conv
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/sshpk-sign
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/sshpk-verify
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/uuid
      /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/which
```

When I tried `brew prune`, I got:

```
newmbp$ brew link node
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.11.0
```

I noticed the files (to be linked or unlinked) are in separate folders, but have been struggling to understand the implications of having files in `/usr/local/Cellar` vs in `/usr/local/lib`

The precipitating factor that led to all of this was the fan on my laptop runs furiously from time to time, often while MAMP is running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`brew cleanup --prune-prefix` (ex- `brew prune`) removed the broken symlinks, so the issue should be gone.

The fact that `brew link node` complains has nothing to do with this; it’s a completely different command. It’s not even an error, just a warning: "you asked me to link `node` but it’s already linked" so everything’s fine here.

---

Homebrew installs its files in `/usr/local/Cellar`. On the other hand, `/usr/local/lib` is a shared directory commonly used for libraries. In order for software to find libs Homebrew installed, it symlinks them in it.

For example, let’s say you have a formula `foo` version 1.2.3 that installs a library `bar`. After running `brew install foo` you should get something like this:

```
# the library files
/usr/local/Cellar/foo/1.2.3/lib/bar
# a symlink to the library files from /usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/bar -> /usr/local/Cellar/foo/1.2.3/lib/bar
```

If you `brew uninstall foo`, it removes both the library files and the symlink.

Those Homebrew symlinks can be manipulated with `brew unlink <formula>` (remove them) and `brew link <formula>` (add them). `brew install` runs `brew link` for you so you don’t need to. This is the reason why you get a warning: your Node symlinks already exist.

`brew doctor` performs various checks, including `check_for_broken_symlinks`. This one looks into directories such as `/usr/local/var` or `/usr/local/lib` for broken symlinks. A broken symlink is a symlink whose target doesn’t exist, often because it has been removed.

The important point to understand here is that Homebrew looks at *all* symlinks, not just the ones it created. Broken symlinks *may* cause issues, which is why Homebrew warns you about them, but if everything’s working fine for you feel free to ignore the warning.

Comment: So I conflated two separate issues. Would the location of certain files (`/usr/local/Cellar` vs `/usr/local/lib`) have anything to do with the complaints or errors?

Comment: @YCode I added an explanation regarding the different paths.

Comment: Thank you for the followup! I re-read your response (and the example) and I think I finally got it (though I should have figured it out already using your original explanation). The challenge is to figure out whether a broken program has to do with Brew's warnings.

Comment: as of the day of this comment, `brew prune` has been deprecated. `brew cleanup` still finds the broken symlinks but doesn't remove them :/

Comment: @ykadaru thanks for the heads up! I edited my answer to use `brew cleanup --prune-prefix` instead, which should have the same effect.